# Can the proof only be the stateful?

Tags: provable-security, chosen-plaintext-attack, indistinguishability

Let SE be stateful encryption.
Then, it is well known that the oracle for the security proof becomes stateful too. (We only consider the IND-CPA security game.)

On the other hand, assume that E is stateless encryption.
Then, can the challenger for proving the IND-CPA security of E behavior as astateful encryption scheme?
During the security game, can the challenger abort depending on previously queried messages?
I think this situation is very awkward and it trivially achieves weaker security, but it might be a useful technique to provide the security of some schemes. If possible, how weak is the security definition rather than the conventional IND-CPA?